# adding wider image to content editor web part in edit mode makes it overlap

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When I am editing content editor webpart and add a image to it, it is fine for images that are not too wide. But if the image is too wide, the content editor webpart expands and it overlaps on the other content editor webparts.

I can solve this by clicking on edit source and changing the width like,

```
<img src="someSource" style="width:100%"/>
```

or using `max-width:100%` in css

But is there a configuration setting in sharepoint, that prevents this overlapping? or are there any better way for solving this?

Comment: You can set the width of the content editor webpart by setting it's width in the Appearance. But one disadvantage of this is if the photo is wider than the width, there would be a scroll bar in the content editor. Just sharing this, don't know if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a SharePoint website before and from what I remember there isn't a way to make the default not overlap. I always had to go into the source code or change the size of the image before hand.

SharePoint has some funny settings like that unfortunately.

You could add a img class to make images always style="width:100%" and then reference that whenever you insert an image.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by referring custom CSS to the page where you have added the content editor .

Here "**s4-wpTopTable**" is the class of my content editor in sharepoint 2010 , please check yours by F12 developer tool

```
.s4-wpTopTable{
width : 49% !important;
max-width : 49% !important
}
 .s4-wpTopTable img{
 max-width : 49% !important

 }
```